# Activiti Spring Boot Strong UUID

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

How to enable springboot activiti based project to enable UUID for the IDs across workflow.
Possible approach is to add the property configuration for StrongUUID. 
But do i need to create activiti.cfg file and have the details of property for Id generator and place id in the class-path. Currently i don't have activiti cfg file i have only the activiti BPM file.

```
<property name="idGenerator">
<bean class="org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.StrongUuidGenerator" />
```

Is there a way where i can add configuration for the id generation?

Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the activiti spring boot implementation you can access the process engine prior to it's initialization using the ProcessEngineConfigurationConfigurer. Refer to the following Alfresco forum question for details of how to do this:

https://community.alfresco.com/message/805701-re-activitispring-boot-disable-activiti-table-generation-on-startup-if-tables-exist?commentID=805701#comment-805701

Once you have access to the ProcessEngineConfiguration you can create the StrongUUID bean as you would in a standard installation.